# Parallelism - "answering" or "would answer"

Tags: parallelism

Is my correction correct, as there is parallelism error?

> **Original:** In exchange, he agreed that the ABC would operate under the
>   jurisdiction of the Defense and Interior Ministries, rather than **answering directly** to him.
>
> **corrected:** In exchange, he agreed that the ABC would operate under the
>   jurisdiction of the Defense and Interior Ministries, rather than **directly answer** to him.

**Reason:** I think **[ABC would]** is common for both the clauses 
i.e.

***[ABC would]*** **operate** under the jurisdiction of the Defense and Interior Ministries, rather than ***[ABC would]* directly answer** to him

Comment: I agree, but I would use "answer directly" because I like to put adverbs directly after verbs if the meaning is not affected. So "would operate under" and "would answer directly".

Comment: Do you have any rule name or website for reference?

Comment: You can search on "adverb placement English" and there are many references. I don't know a rule offhand, which is why I wrote a comment.